# Hint for Big Bang in Genesis

Tags: parashat-bereishit, science, creation

Has anyone found a hint for the Big Bang event postulated by modern cosmology, i.e. that the Universe expanded from a "point," in the Genesis account?

Some kind of torah code or other sort of hint. I assume such an important event has a hint in the torah. (regardless whether or not it actually happened, at least looks like it did from a scientific viewpoint)

Comment: see the question, answer and comments [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68979/what-was-the-source-of-the-primordial-light-on-the-first-day-of-creation/68982#68982)

Comment: What do you mean by "Big Bang event"? The main *chidush* associated with that term is that there was a beginning to the Universe, that it didn't exist forever. We don't need Torah codes (or to get too many words in) to find that concept in the Torah.

Comment: I was referred just last week to the Ramban; his commentary on Ber. 1 works as a prototype for the Big Bang theory.

Comment: How about verse 3.

Comment: @IsaacMoses not only a beginning but a beginning from a "point" which subsequently expanded and the rest of the unfolding. its quite an interesting story. perhaps even shesiya is close. i thought maybe the point tag on the Beis of bereishis.

Comment: some relevant comments over here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68979/what-was-the-source-of-the-primordial-light-on-the-first-day-of-creation#comment197599_68979  If you'd like, I can type that up as an "official" answer...

Comment: "I assume such an important event has a hint in the torah" Other than informing us that the God created the world, why do you assume that the Torah would tell us whether the universe expanded after coming into existence? Why does this matter to us?

Comment: "Some kind of torah code or other sort of hint" Why do you assume that the Torah would deliberately place a message composed of letters spaced far apart that could only be deciphered by looking for it, after one already knows about the phenomenon one is looking for, and knows what to search for. Isn't this pretty pointless?

Comment: @mevaqesh because everything is in the torah.I believe that. do you?

Comment: Does the Torah tell me who will win the world series this year? because... wow... I could really use the cash... @mevaqesh

Comment: @ray Well that is the subject of this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52550/everything-is-in-the-torah and this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60002/does-the-torah-know-about-quantum-mechanics-and-dna-synthesis/60004#60004 and this question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56724/are-all-answers-in-the-torah/56727#56727 and this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52553/there-is-no-question-in-the-world-whose-answer-cannot-be-found-in-torah.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky vilna gaon says everything is in there, not just in a general way but even every detail.

Comment: @mevaqesh so you dont know? i see you are quite a baki in the shas of mi yodeya

Comment: @ray How do you know that he says that?

Comment: @mevaqesh http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71453/1857

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the first Ramban in Sefer Bereishis. He makes reference to an idea that Hashem created a "yuli" and created everything else from that. I've seen two explanations for this: one is the atom and the other is the Big Bang.

Comment: I've heard "yuli" explained as raw energy.

Answer (score 0):

The Big Bang essentially posits that our world was spawned from another world which the Big Bang event itself remains our only connection to.

This seems to be totally congruous with the idea of bereishis bara elokim.

Comment: "The Big Bang essentially posits that our world was spawned from another world which the Big Bang event itself remains our only connection to" That was not my understanding. Do you have a source?

Comment: "This seems to be totally congruous with the idea of bereishis bara elokim." Why?

Comment: "spawned from another world" - there is no evidence whatsoever for this. physicists will tell you anything we say about the origin of the big bang is pure speculation which cannot be tested

Comment: The BBT ONLY posits the existence of a singularity. Many proponents of BBT might believe in the existence of a universe before that, but that is no more part of the BBT than the fact that many proponents of evolution believe chocolate is the best flavor of ice cream... :)

Comment: @mevaqesh I think the answer is referring to the passage in talmud that states that this universe is only one of a sequences (bara - shis).

Comment: Do you really think that is "The Big Bang"'s essential point? What led you to think that? Secondly, in what way do you find that to be totally congruous with the words Bereishis Bara Elokim? I know many people who would find those two concepts to be entirely incongruous.